# Using Dropbox iOS API and NSDate to either download or upload the file not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, compare, nsdate, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox iOS API to sync between different devices. Using the following code, I am trying to compare the dates when the file was modified to either download/upload the newer file. The problem is, that it is just downloading and never uploading. Any hints?

```
- (void)dropboxAuth {
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] link];
    }
    else {
        NSString *filename = @"NotesList.plist";
        NSString *destDir = @"/";
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *address = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NotesList.plist"];

        [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];

        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:address]) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:address error:&error];
            NSDate *fileDate =[dictionary objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

            if ([[fileDate earlierDate:self.metaData.lastModifiedDate]isEqualToDate:fileDate]) {
                [self.restClient loadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", destDir, filename]
                                 intoPath:address];
                NSLog(@"Downloading");
            }
            else if ([[self.metaData.lastModifiedDate earlierDate:fileDate] isEqualToDate:self.metaData.lastModifiedDate]) {
                [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir fromPath:address];
                NSLog(@"Uploading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found a helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950168/a-simple-sync-with-the-iphone-dropbox-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is suspect:

```
if ([[fileDate earlierDate:self.metaData.lastModifiedDate]isEqualToDate:fileDate]) {
```

This is always evaluating to true, which means to me either that `self.metaData.lastModifiedDate` is equal to `fileDate` or that `fileDate` is always the earlier of the two dates.

Honestly, I'm having trouble even parsing these conditionals.  What happens if you try evaluating it another way? like this, for instance:

```
if (nil == fileDate || fileDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < self.metaData.lastModifiedDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
{
    [self.restClient loadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", destDir, filename]
                         intoPath:address];
    NSLog(@"Downloading");
}
else if (nil != fileDate && fileDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > self.metaData.lastModifiedDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) {
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir fromPath:address];
    NSLog(@"Uploading");
}
```

Also, if the dates are equal, I assume you want to do neither, right?