# How to download file from dropbox using Dropbox Sync API iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dropbox

I am using [Dropbox Sync API sdk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios) it display all folder and file but we can not download file
i am using this code:

```
  DBFilesystem *filesystem;
  DBFile *file = [_filesystem openFile:info.path error:nil];
   NSData *imagedata=[file readData:nil];
  [fileMan createFileAtPath:Image_filePath  contents:**data** attributes:nil];
  NSLog(@"flao=%d",[file writeData:imagedata error:nil]);
  // it return 1
```

I am getting NSData but i can't store in document directory.
I check below links but no success

[Dropbox Sync API iOS copy files to app documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494546/dropbox-sync-api-ios-copy-files-to-app-documents)

[Data syncing with DropBox API and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811932/data-syncing-with-dropbox-api-and-ios)

Please Help me.

Comment: have you implemented  below function and are you getting any values in below method my friend???
  - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
      }

Comment: @NiravPatel restclient is core api function so this function is allowed in sync app

Comment: Try to check errors. 
`NSError *error;
NSData *imagedata = [file readData:&error];
if (error)
   NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);`

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox takes time to cache a file, you can set up a block to monitor when the cache is completed:

```
__block MyViewController *me = self;
[self.dropboxFile addObserver:self block:^() { [me monitorDropboxFile:@"Sync"]; }];
```

inside the observer:

```
- (void)monitorDropboxFile:(NSString *)caller
{
    if (self.dropboxFile.status.cached) {
        ; // Good to go, the file is cached
    } else {
        ; // download in progress
    }
}
```

Or, there is a simpler way, use `readHandle`:

```
(DBFile *)file;
// ...  
DBError *dbError;
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [file readHandle:&dbError];
```

As documented in the Dropbox API header:

> /** Returns a read-only file handle for the file. If the file is not
>   cached then the method will  block until the file is downloaded.
>   @return A file handle if the file can be read, or `nil` if an error
>   occurred.  */

The file handle is ready when returned. However, you might like to put `readHandle` in a background thread if the app has to be responsive during file download.