# Determine if update needed by date

Tags: python, date, dropbox-api

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811932/data-syncing-with-dropbox-api-and-ios), and it somewhat provides what I needed, but I wanted to ask about any problems that can occur when storing and pulling files from Dropbox based on date.

I have an employee list with the filename `empList.txt` sitting in a DB folder named `empList-20171106_183150`. The folder name has the year,month,day and time right down to the second, appended to it`(YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS)`.

Locally, I have a python script that has a log(txt), which just contains the date of the last time the script went and downloaded the updated list. The log looks like this if the last time the script ran was on Nov 01 2017 at 9am

```
20171101_090020
```

If I used Dropbox and a script written in Python to download the lastest version based on the date/time, are there any disadvantages to doing this?

I just compare the date stored in the log, to the date appended on the folder. If the date of folder in DB is greater, a download is needed. My only concern is during the date comparison and download, one of the managers might upload a new list, meaning I would have to run the script again.

How do complete programs such as MalwareBytes or internet security software manage a user downloading an update when they make a new update available at the same time? For me, I just run the update again to make sure while I was checkking/updating a new update wasn't made available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using date comparisons, because of potential issues with race conditions, like you mentioned, etc.

The Dropbox API exposes ways to tell if things have changed instead. Specifically, when downloading the file, you should store the metadata for the version of the file you downloaded. In particular, [`FileMetadata.rev`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata.rev) or [`FileMetadata.content_hash`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata.content_hash) would be useful.

If you then check again later and either of those values are different than the last one you downloaded, you know something has changed, so you should re-download.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback